# Using Stripe webhooks with graphql-yoga and Prisma

Tags: express, stripe-payments, graphql, webhooks, prisma

I'm having some trouble finding how to intercept Stripe webhook calls in my application. I use graphql-yoga (express) and prisma.

I have to listen to payment failure calls from Stripe so I can edit the corresponding user profile.

Thanks for the help!

Stripe webhook calls look like so :

```
{
  "created": 1326853478,
  "id": "charge.expired_00000000000000",
  "type": "charge.expired",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "ch_00000000000000",
      "object": "charge",
      "amount": 100,
      "captured": false,
      "created": 1537153592,
      "currency": "usd",
      "customer": null,
      "description": "My First Test Charge (created for API docs)",
      "invoice": null,
      "livemode": false,
      "on_behalf_of": null,
      "order": null,
      "outcome": null,
      "paid": true,
      "receipt_email": null,
      "receipt_number": null,
      "refunded": false,
      "review": null,
      "shipping": null,
      "source": {
        "id": "card_00000000000000",
        "object": "card",
        "address_city": null,
        "address_country": null,
        "address_line1": null,
        "address_line1_check": null,
        "address_line2": null,
        "address_state": null,
        "address_zip": "12919",
        "address_zip_check": "pass",
        "brand": "Visa",
        "country": "US",
        "customer": "cus_00000000000000",
        "cvc_check": null,
        "name": null,
        "tokenization_method": null
      },
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "status": "succeeded",
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since Stripe Webhook returns a generic http `POST` with `JSON` payload, it will not format the `event` data according to `Graphql` language query.

For now, what you can do is to expose a normal `REST` API endpoint using `Graphql-Yoga`'s `express`[0]

I have composed a working sample code you can try it out

```js
const { GraphQLServer } = require('graphql-yoga')
const typeDefs = `
  type Query {
    hello(name: String): String!
  }
`
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: (_, { name }) => `Hello ${name || 'World'}`,
  },
}

const server = new GraphQLServer({ typeDefs, resolvers, skipValidation: true })
server.express.use('/api/stripe/webhooks', (req, res) => {
    // Handle your callback here !!!!
    res.status(200).send();
})

server.start(() => console.log('Server is running on localhost:4000'))
```

Let me know if the above helps.

[0] https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga#how-to-eject-from-the-standard-express-setup

Comment: Thanks for the help ! This sure is a great solution. The only thing I don't like about using a server to listen for webhooks is that in case of a downtime, things could get quite messy. I was thinking about maybe implementing it on a "serverless" solution or something like so

Comment: Actually, Stripe webhook has a retry mechanism in case your server fails. It will retry up to 72hours (https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#responding-to-a-webhook) if case your server is down (hopefully your server is not down that long :) ). But definitely you can use `serverless` approach, parse the response and proxy the `webhook` to your `Graphql` endpoint matching the Schema

Comment: It is great, but how do you access to the ’ctx’ variable inside the express server?